# Tricky positioning and sizing of div

Tags: css, html

I have a div that is 100% wide by 180px tall - the header.

Underneath that I want a div that stretches right to the bottom with a white background - the content div). The way I have implemented at the moment is that the content div is ALWAYS 180px underneath the browsing window (almost like a 180px scroll-down no matter the browser window size).

Previously I have tried turning overflow:hidden on, but for the actual content, it MAY have to scroll down so I don't want to disable this functionality.

Below is a drawing of what I want:

[image]

Does anyone know a way to counteract this?

EDIT:

Apologies for not being clear. I want the content div to stretch to the bottom of the window in all circumstances but setting the value to 100% does not do me any good as it's then 180px below the viewport because the header pushes it down.

Comment: What is the actual question ?

Comment: He wants the content div to always stretch to the bottom of the browser viewport.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body style='background:black;'>
<div style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:180px;' align='center'><div style='width:900px;background:blue;'>content<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div></div>
<div style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:180px;left:0px;top:0px;background:white;;'>header</div>
</body></html>
```

VERSION 2.0 (hahah lol):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body style='background:black;'>
<div style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;' align='center'>
    <div style='width:900px;height:100%;background:blue;' align='center'>
        <div style='position:fixed;width:900px;height:100%;background:blue;display:block;' align='center'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style='position:absolute;width:100%;left:0px;top:180px;' align='center'>
    <div style='width:900px;' align='center'>


hello<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>aaa<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>bbb<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>ccc<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>ddd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br

><br><br><br>eee
    </div>
</div>
<div style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:180px;left:0px;top:0px;background:white;;'>header</div>
</body></html>
```

try it and i think this is what you looking for! :)
so first you add 100% width and height div to fill whole screen and all inside that div positioned in center and in center you add another diw wich will be lets say 900 width and here will be all the content. after that you add header wich is 100% width and 180 height all those divs position is absolute so you can type where each one goes. top 0px left 0px for header and for content top 180px so it will become after the header! :)

Comment: do you mean define the header BELOW the content in the html and then just CSS it back to the top?

Comment: Good, but this is one of the issues I've been having, with not much content the blue only stretches around the words, not to the bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/ygtvZ/

Comment: just add one more div inside of content div and give him height:100%;

Answer (score 0):

`position: relative; top: 0; bottom: 0;` on the content div. This should stretch it to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

What about this, you will need to have a content div and a content-container div, with the container...containing the content! :) You'll need to fiddle with these until you get what you want but the main issue is using bottom:0 and the positions for each element.

```
content {bottom:0; min-height:180px; position:absolute;}
content-container {position:relative;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking right, but one important thing to remember is that body and html elements need to have width and heigh set on 100% also.

Have a look on this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: gray;
        }
        #header {
            background: red;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #main {
            background: blue;
            height: 100%;
            width: 400px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you run it, the only problem you'll see is that a scroll bars appear. Thats because `#main` div will have the window height and there are more 100px from the header.

The solution I suggest is to make the header float over the main div, and then add another div inside `#main` also absolutely positioned 100px bellow, so you can work inside it without much trouble. The full code is then:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: gray;
        }
        #header {
            background: red;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 20;
        }
        #main {
            background: blue;
            height: 100%;
            width: 400px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 10;
        }
        #main #content {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        <p style="margin:0">Paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Make sure you use a reset file. Margins like the ones paragraph element has would mess the layout quite a bit.

**Update:**
As pointed, the solution brings overflow problems. So here is a better version:

Change the 2 css blocks as follows:

```
#main {
    background: blue;
    min-height: 100%; /* Changed */
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
#main #content {
    padding-top: 100px; /* Changed */
}
```

And make sure the markup is this way (like the last example):

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

That should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

i used the same technique as sticky footer http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/. check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kuyabiye/K5pYe/